# VB script + find the PATH of the required directory under D: drive

Tags: vbscript

How to find the SUB_MAIN directory full PATH by VB script?

RULE:  SUB_MAIN directory always under MAIN directory

SUB_MAIN directory could be anywhere in the PATH as the following examples:

```
D:\...\...\...\MAIN\SUB_MAIN

Or

D:\...\...\MAIN\SUB_MAIN

Or   

D:\...\...\... \...\...\MAIN\SUB_MAIN
```

Example of PATH that VB script need to find:

PATH=D:\scripts\win\my_folder\MAIN\SUB_MAIN

Answer (score 0):

Use FileSystemObject and recursively go through the sub-folders until you find the folder you are looking for.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6dw7aeh(v=VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6dw7aeh%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Not exactly how I would do it but you should get the point

```
Option Explicit

Dim sub_mains

function getfolders(rootfolder)

    Dim FSO, fold, folds,folds1

    set FSO =  CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set fold = FSO.GetFolder(rootfolder)
    Set folds = fold.SubFolders
    For Each folds1 in folds
        getfolders(folds1.path)
        if InStr(folds1.path,"sub_main") > 0 then
            sub_mains = sub_mains + folds1.path + ":" 
        End If
    Next

end function
getfolders("C:\test")

MsgBox(sub_mains)
```

Comment: @Gratzy which param defined the SUB_MAIN directory and which the MAIN directory?

Comment: @jon you pass in your root directory and stop when you find sub_main

Comment: @Gratzy but if I have more then one SUB_MAIN dir?  not under MAIN dir

Comment: PATH final results must be when SUB_MAIN is under MAIN !

Comment: did you mean that rootfolder is the MAIN dir?

Comment: I updated it.  It now builds a string sub_mains that is a concatenation of all of the full paths containing sub_main in them starting at root.  I think you should be able to get it from there.

Comment: @Gratzy how to copy the code - I get one line when I copy your code?Option Explicit  Dim sub_mains  function getfolders(rootfolder)      Dim FSO, fold, folds,folds1      set FSO =  CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")      Set fold = FSO.GetFolder(rootfolder)     Set folds = fold.SubFolders     For Each folds1 in folds         getfolders(folds1.path)         if InStr(folds1.path,"sub_main") > 0 then             sub_mains = sub_mains + folds1.path + ":"          End If     Next  end function getfolders("C:\test")  MsgBox(sub_mains)

Comment: @jon it copies fine for me, I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: OK I copy it but which param defined the MAIN dir? ( i test it but its not find the PATH?

Comment: substitute "c:\test" with whatever the root is you want to start searching at.  In your case I think its "d:\"